# bulk deleting empty items in the media library

Tags: media-library, bulk, customization

I wrote a function, which should rename my attachments, based on the post title. Unfortunately this function created over 10.000 empty instances in my media-library, before I was able to stop it. 
The instances are all attached to a single post, which I could delete if it's necessary.

I'm really sorry to bother you with the ask for help, but I'm a bit scared to screw things up again.

Comment: How exactly do these empty instances look like?

Comment: hard to describe, cause they are invisible, like ghosts. I made a [screenshot](http://oi47.tinypic.com/2edb2j8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't expected an answer to this question I tried it with [wp_delete_attachment();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment). 
I wrote this function on a random page of my site (since the site isn't live yet) and executed it from there.

```
$attac_kill_ids = range(1235, 22686); //fill an array with the post_ids from the empty instances                    
foreach( $attac_kill_ids as $kill_id ){
    $kill_post = get_post( $kill_id );
    if( $kill_post ) {
        wp_delete_attachment( $kill_id, true );
        echo '<br />killed #' . $kill_id;
    }
    else continue;
}
```

'*delete*' would be more precise, but '*kill*' sounds more dangerous and keeps me concentrated thereby.

Then I used this line in phpMyAdmin to set the ID-counter back to 810

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT=810
```